# Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: default

Tags: javascript, dotenv, javascript-import

This is my file structure.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dqZ0.png)

This is the location of dotenv folder.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQbhJ.png)

This is code for import and get API_KEY from ../../.env file.

```
import dotenv from '../../node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js';
dotenv.config({ path: '.env' });
const apiKey = process.env.API_KEY;
console.log(apiKey);
```

This .js file location is ./app/js/app.js. When I run this code in web browser is trow this error message "Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: default"

How can I solve this problem?
Have I any other option to import my API_KEY from ../../.env file?

Comment: Why do you use `import dotenv from '../../node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js';` to import the module? Why not `import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'` as described in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)? Are you trying to use this module in a browser? I don't think it will work.

Comment: because when I use `import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'` this, my browser console show this error `Uncaught TypeError: The specifier “.dotenv” was a bare specifier, but was not remapped to anything. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.`

Comment: I don't think you can use this module in the browser. It uses Node.js functions to read a file from a local file system. That's not possible in a browser.

Comment: So can you provide me a solution to import my API_KEY ( It is inside of .env file ) into current app.js file ?

Comment: You could use a build system like Webpack

Comment: Hi, please do not use imgs for important parts. Read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417)